# Can I Select Distinct inside a where and get all selects in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have this:

---

```
SELECT FirstName
FROM MAIN_TABLE_LEVEL100
WHERE FirstName IN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT FirstName
        FROM MAIN_TABLE_LEVEL100
    )
ORDER BY `level` DESC, `time` DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

---

Im trying to get top 10 diferents names order by level and time, but it doesn't work, if someone can help me please, thanks.

Comment: I found the answer!! : **************************************************************************************************************
SELECT o.FirstName, o.Level, o.Time, o.City
 FROM `MAIN_TABLE_LEVEL100` o                    # 'o' from 'bigger points'
   LEFT JOIN `MAIN_TABLE_LEVEL100` b             # 'b' from 'bigger after o'
       ON o.FirstName = b.FirstName AND o.Points < b.Points
 WHERE b.Points is NULL
 ORDER BY `o`.`Points`  DESC
 LIMIT 0,10

Answer (score 0):

Your where clause is doing nothing, you just repeated the same select that you had above. As long as level and time are in 'MAIN_TABLE_LEVEL100' you don't even need a where clause. This should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, level, time
FROM MAIN_TABLE_LEVEL100
ORDER BY level DESC, time DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: but the problem is still there, i mean, i dont wanna have 2 firstName repeated in the result, and im getting already this:

-firstname : beru - level:1 - time:2
-firstname : beru -level:4 - time:3
and i want just recieve:
-firstname beru level 4 time 3
im not sure if im explaining this rigth way

Comment: im using this: 
---------------------------------
SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, Level, Time, City FROM MAIN_TABLE_LEVEL100 ORDER BY `level` DESC, `time` DESC LIMIT 0,10
----------------------------------------
But it give and repeated firstName, with diferents level, and i just dont wanna have the same name, i dont care about level and time repeated, if u have some idea please, thanks

Comment: You should be able to use a GROUP BY FirstName at the end to stop the duplicates.

Comment: Yes, i use this :*******************************************
 SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, Level, Time, City FROM MAIN_TABLE_LEVEL100 GROUP BY FirstName ORDER BY level DESC, time DESC LIMIT 0,10*************************** but it still doesnt work, it doesnt show me the best top 10 :/

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple lines because of time. Try rolling the data together first.
I'm not familiar with mySql, but using generic SQL syntax it would be something like this:

```
SELECT b.FirstName
FROM (SELECT a.FirstName, a.Level, MAX(a.Time) AS tm FROM MAIN_TABLE_LEVEL100 as a GROUP BY a.FirstName, a.Level) AS b
ORDER By b.Level, b.tm
```

Comment: it doesnt work, but i think I need use a subsequence

Comment: I left off the Group By clause used by the Max function. I think my brain was out to lunch.  I edited the SQL statement. This should get you closer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use `GROUP BY` .DISTINCT work only with indexed field in some situation.

Comment: group by, ignore not repeated names idk why, but that is a big problem :/

Comment: I don't understand you :) Group by not ignore anything. Can you provide some sample data, and show what you expected.

Comment: Okay, for example, in my table i have this 3 Persons:
*******************************
    1. NAME Señor Beru EUW LEVEL 100  TIME 35 CITY ES
*******************************
    2. vane  LEVEL 100  TIME 15 CITY ES
*******************************
    3. vane  LEVEL 100  TIME 25 CITY ES
*******************************
The output I want, is just see person 1, and person 2, but not person 3, because existe another with the same name and better time, im not sure if im explaining my sleft in good way?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I finally found the right answer!:

```
SELECT o.FirstName, o.Level, o.Time, o.City
FROM `MAIN_TABLE_LEVEL100` o                    # 'o' from 'bigger points'
  LEFT JOIN `MAIN_TABLE_LEVEL100` b             # 'b' from 'bigger after o'
      ON o.FirstName = b.FirstName AND o.Points < b.Points
WHERE b.Points is NULL
ORDER BY `o`.`Points`  DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

thanks everyone, i hope someone need it ;)